# I was writing a program for finding a file's characteristics. Why is it showing "unclosed character literal" in s.lastIndexOf String function?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, char

I was writing a program to find a file's path, name and extension. Here is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class File_characteristics
{
    public static void main()
    {
        System.out.println("\f"); // clearing the screen
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the file's path");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        int a = s.lastIndexOf('\'); // Error of "unclosed character literal" is showing up
        String b = s.substring(0,a+1); // finding the file's path
        int c = s.lastIndexOf('.'); // Error isn't showing here though
        String d = s.substring(a+1,c); // finding the file's name
        String e = s.substring(c+1); // finding the file's extension
        System.out.println("Path: "+b);
        System.out.println("File name: "+d);
        System.out.println("Extension: "+e);
    } // method ends
} // class ends
```

For some reason, it shows "unclosed character literal" error on the line  `int a = s.lastIndexOf('\');`and I have no idea why. I have added the single quotation marks around the character as such '' but it's showing the error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character, which marks the beginning of an escape sequence. The compiler understands that you are beginning a character literal (with `'`) then attempting to write a single quote (with `\'`), so the closing `'` is missing, and hence the error. To refer to `"\"` literally, you need to escape it as well:

```
int a = s.lastIndexOf('\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [file](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-file-class) class to extract the details. Take a look at the code below:

```
    File file = new File("filePath");
    String path = file.getParent();
    String fileNameWithExtension = file.getName();
    String[] split = fileNameWithExtension.split("\\.");
    String fileName = split[0];
    String extension = split[1];
    System.out.println("Path: "+path);
    System.out.println("File name: "+fileName);
    System.out.println("Extension: "+extension);
```